# Strategies for Tap Tap Revenge 4?

Tags: tap-tap-revenge-4

When I play *Tap Tap Revenge 4* on my Ipod Touch, I have difficulties playing the songs on harder levels. I have no problem with the songs or the difficulty modes, but with my fingers. Can anyone tell me a strategy or technique to use so I can play this game easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the best way to do it is to use three fingers, one per lane.  If that doesn't work, just try experimenting with different variations of where you hold your hand.  Some people play with two fingers, some with only one (except for the multi-note sections, obviously).

Comment: uh...oooooookkkkk'